# Register rest route in a class library do not work

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I have run in two an issue with building a WP plugin, the issue is that I want to use the WP Rest API and to extend it, with my own endpoint.

I'm writing the code using a class object, I register add_action('rest_api_init' the problem I have is that the endpoint is now showing up in the route.

Here is the code when I initialise the plugin.

```
class ThorAdmin {

    public function __construct() {

        // Activation and deactivation hook.
        register_activation_hook(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/wp-thor-fcm/wp-thor-fcm.php',  array($this, 'thor_fcm_activate'));
        register_deactivation_hook( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/wp-thor-fcm/wp-thor-fcm.php',  array($this, 'thor_fcm_deactivate' ));

        // Admin Menu
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'thor_admin_menu'));
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'thor_fcm_settings_init'));

        add_action('wpmu_new_blog',  array($this, 'thor_on_new_blog', 10, 6));      
        add_action('activate_blog',  array($this, 'thor_on_new_blog', 10, 6));

        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'thor_head') );            

        //The Following registers an api route with multiple parameters. 
        add_action('rest_api_init', array($this, 'add_thor_fcm_route'));

        add_filter('admin_footer_text', array($this, 'thor_fcm_admin_footer'));
    }
```

Here are functions that I call from add_action('rest_api_init', array($this, 'add_thor_fcm_route'));

```
/**
 * Registers the routes for all and single options
 *
 */
function add_thor_fcm_route() {

    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2/thorfcmapi', '/options', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => array ($this, 'add_fcm_option_route')
    ) );
}

/**
 * The callback for the `wp/v2/thorfcmapi/options` endpoint
 */
function add_fcm_option_route( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    if($request['option']) {
        return get_field($request['option'], 'option');
    }

    return get_fields('option');
}
```

When I do this command added to my url

```
 ?rest_route=/
```

I do not find my route wp/v2/thorfcmapi in the list of routes

If I take the same code, make a separate plugin just with this code

```
 add_action('rest_api_init', 'add_thor_FCM_Route_test' );

 function add_thor_FCM_Route_test() {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2/thorfcmapi', '/options', array(
       'methods' => GET,
       'callback' => 'add_FCM_Option_Route_test'
  ) );
}

/**
* The callback for the `wp/v2/thorfcmapi/options` endpoint
*/
function add_FCM_Option_Route_test( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
  if($request['option']) {
    return get_field($request['option'], 'option');
 }

   return get_fields('option');
```

}

The only different is that I do not embed within a class and I do not use $this, it works get registered as a route. And I can make an API call.

I do not want to plugins, I want the code towork in my class - I took the simplified code and added it in my plugin (1st example), I added it first outside of the class, it still did not register the route and no errors.

What am I doing wrong?

What is it that I do not seems to understand to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

I found the issue - it was related to using is_admin() - if is_admin is true I could not register a rest route. Case closed.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: i did not faced this issue, but code in your question solved my problem. 'callback' => array ($this, 'add_fcm_option_route'). I was not using "array($this".

Comment: Also, checkout [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/349511) answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

check you theme or child theme is active .